# Python nested function calling multiple ()

Tags: python, function, nested

Can someone explain the logic or syntax of 
`function()()`
or 
`function(function)()`

An example:
I can't seem to grasp the idea of how this actually works

`func2(func1)("bye")`

```
def func2(fn):
    print("func2")
    def func3(text2):
        print("func3")
        print(text2)
    return func3

def func1():
    print("func1")

func2(func1)("bye")
```

Output:

```
func2
func3
bye
```

Comment: A function can return another function. The first call, calls the first function and the second calls the function returned by the first

Comment: func2(func1)("bye")  -> ("bye") is not calling a nested function but passing a parameter. Can't grasp this parameter passing

Comment: Yes, it is calling a nested function. It's unclear what you mean by *"parameter passing"*.

Answer (score 2):

A function can return another function. The first call, calls the first function and the second calls the function returned by the first.

The nested definitions are a separate concept not related to the question (about functions returning functions), since func3 exists only on the scope of func2, which may create confusion.

Here is a simpler example:

```
def f1(a):
    print("Function f1 called")
    print(a)

def f2(b):
    print("Function f2 called")
    print(b)
    return f1


f2(1)(2)
Function f2 called
1
Function f1 called
2
```